# Data Not Pass to Controller

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am displaying list of data now on click of submit button the data should go to the Specific Controller but I am not able to do that.  Below is the Partial View on which I am displaying data:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.TicketDetails>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitHours", "TicketDetails", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <hr />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Ticket No.</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action Date</th>
                <th>Billable Hours</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var ticketdata in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => ticketdata.TicketDetailsGuid)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => ticketdata.Summary)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => ticketdata.CAStatus)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => ticketdata.ActionDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Comment", null, new { @class = "form-control" })  </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>

    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    @*<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SubmitHours", "TicketDetails")'" />*@
}
```

The controller from which above data is display is given below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<TicketDetails> _TicketDetails = new List<TicketDetails>();
            _TicketDetails = (from ticketdata in _entities.AccMng_TicketDetails.AsEnumerable()
                                     select new TicketDetails
                                     {TicketDetailsGuid = ticketdata.TicketDetailsGuid,
                                      ActionBy = ticketdata.ActionBy,
                                     CAStatus = ticketdata.CAStatus,
                                     Comment = ticketdata.Comment,
                                     Summary = ticketdata.Summary}).ToList();

            return View(_TicketDetails);
        }
```

Now here I just want to send that Partial data to a Specific controller but that data not comes:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitHours(List<AccMng_TicketDetails> _AccMng_TicketDetails)
        {
            return View(_AccMng_TicketDetails);
        }
```

Comment: You form does not contain any form controls for properties associated with `AccMng_TicketDetails` - the only form control you have is for a property named `Comment` so the method parameter would need to be `IEnumerable<string> comment` (and as a side note, your `TextBox()` is generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the reply but after removing comment textbox data is not pass

Comment: If you have removed the textbox then there is nothing that can be posted. A form only posts the name/value pairs of its form controls (and you do not have any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would recommend at least use List instead of IEnumerable as your model definition to use the index-based approach, as @Leonardo said.  If you are just trying to only pass back the comments for each row, change the comment box to an expression-based helper, and add a hidden field for the GUID (so it posts back to the controller).

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
     <tr>
       <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].TicketDetailsGuid)
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].TicketDetailsGuid)
       </td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Summary)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].CAStatus)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ActionDate)</td>
       <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Comment, new { @class = "form-control" })  </td>
     </tr>
}
```

When the page posts back, it will postback a list of objects with TicketDetailsGuid and Comment fields populated only (because they are inputs in the UI).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use use @EditorFor instead DisplayFor and @for instead @foreach and referer any item with it's index like

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Summary)
```