# Post HTML Table to Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form where users can dynamically add entries to a html table from a dropdownbox. Each entry is added as its own row. This is fairly easily done in javascript:

```
function addProduct(int type) {
    var product = getProduct(type); // The method just fetches the product from the database
    $('selectedProductsTable').append("<tr><td>" + product.Name +"</td><td>" + product.Quantity + "</td></tr>")
}
```

In a second step the contents of the table need to be posted to the controller for further processing. What is the general best practice to get the products i've added as table rows? I could iterate over the rows of the selectedProductsTable but that seems somewhat error prone.

On the other hand i would be open to another way to persist the selected items so that i can post them to the controller. Unfortunately saving them in the session or in the tempData is also not a good option since the selection takes place completely in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only INPUT and SELECT elements get posted back to the server, so you need to store each value in hidden fields to make it back.  You can use the index-based approach to post back an array, which works well.  [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212450/data-not-pass-to-controller/45213853#45213853).

I wrote up a [blog post about dynamic client-side lists](https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2016/06/27/asp-net-mvc-and-client-side-lists-with-kendo/), which might be helpful.  It uses Kendo Core but that would not be required.

Comment: Kendo is not really an option and the problem is that the table rows that contain the selected products shouldn't contain inputs. The values have to be selected based on the standard table definition.

Comment: Yes, I figured Kendo might not be an option; I only include it as a sample.  However, if you want to do a natural POST operation, you have to use inputs.  If you want to do an AJAX post, you can manually collect the data from the cells, generate an array of JSON objects and post that using AJAX.

Comment: I used your approach to model binding while using a partial html template. This seems to do exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `addProduct` populate array with data about products:

```
   var products=[];
function addProduct(int type) {
    var product = getProduct(type); // The method just fetches the product from the database
  products.push(product)
   $('selectedProductsTable').append("<tr><td>" + product.Name +"</td><td>" + 
    product.Quantity + "</td></tr>")
 }
```

and later send it with ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'your url',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //TODO
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(products)
    });
```